# Can one use CSV as an in-memory database with alasql?

Tags: alasql

I currently have data stored in a CSV and want to query this using alasql in node.js. Would it make more sense to store this in an alternative format? My requirements are that it needs to be in-memory, as speed will be paramount.

Would sqlite or indexeddb be the way to go?

My CSV contains around 1.5 million rows (& 20 columns).

Comment: CSV files aren't indexed, so it'd be slower than SQLite, or other actual databases

Comment: Or just import your file. https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/Csv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing an SQL query with unix sort, uniq and awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068977/replacing-an-sql-query-with-unix-sort-uniq-and-awk)